# Clearing floats for just parent container, not ancestors?

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following layout with 2 level float containers:

```
<div id="navigation" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 200px; background-color: #eee">Navigation</div>
<div id="container" style="margin-left: 150px; background-color: #f00">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 100px; background-color: #ff0">Block</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: #f0f">Block</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 50px; background-color: #00f">This Block</div>
</div>
```

You can see it live at http://jsfiddle.net/dNmNj/ .

My intention is to clear floats for `#container` so that the blue block (`This Block`) stays right below the yellow one (not the pink one). However, the result is that it also cleared floats for `#navigation`.

How do I clear floats just for the parent container and not any ancestor containers?

Comment: not sure if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/dNmNj/2/ (added `overflow:hidden` to `#container`)

Comment: Yes thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. Could you explain a bit how come overflow affects floats?

Comment: have added an answer - the overflow hidden thing is something to do with the browsers hasLayout

Comment: @Pete: Uh... no. For one thing, IE is the only browser that uses hasLayout - if it were really a hasLayout issue then the solution would only work on IE.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure why the overflow thing works, it's just a hack I came across.  I never use it though due to it not working in all browsers - that is why I gave the work around in the answer I provided

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by adding `overflow:hidden` to your `#container`:

http://jsfiddle.net/dNmNj/2

this is a good article about clearing floats

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

but the reason your blue div is dropping where it is is because the #container div is not floated - just margin left

The following shows a reworking which is more cross-browser compatible:

http://jsfiddle.net/dNmNj/3/

Comment: @He Shiming: Except the explanation is incorrect. `overflow: hidden` doesn't clear floats, it isn't a hasLayout issue as I've mentioned above, and there isn't much of a difference in browser compatibility between the two examples given here.

Comment: @BoltClock, could you clarify what does `overflow: hidden` do in this case? I'm working with Chrome and IE8, and I just realized this layout doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @Pete, the cross-browser version doesn't quite work in IE8. I'll try and investigate.

Comment: I've managed to get this working in IE by reducing width from 50% to 49%, I guess it's a rounding problem after all.

Comment: It could be a padding or margin problem, they get added on top of the width

Comment: This was bugging the crap out of me.  Thank you very much.